# How to set timeout for gRPC requests in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, grpc

I am using gRPC service with client compiled to Objective-C with  `grpc_objective_c_plugin` from Swift.

I construct `GRPCProtoCall` request object with `client.rpcToDoSomething`, then set proper metadata and then `.start()` it.

How do I set timeout for grpc request?

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite get which gRPC client you are using from your description, but:

- If you are using grpc-swift (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift), you can set the [timeout](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/blob/1ef3b54deacccf9c683cf17a0d442b0b29c7fe66/Sources/gRPC/Channel.swift#L31) property.
- If you are using grpc objective-c (https://github.com/grpc/grpc), it is currently not supported but there is a [pending PR](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/12339) on this and will be available on the next minor or patch release.